# What material is the wrinkled fabric(?) seen on the outside of some capsules and what is its purpose?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, materials, canadarm

For example, the silver material on the Soyuz capsule

[image: Soyuz]

Or the white wrapping on Canadarm and other robotic modules on the ISS

[image: Canadarm]

My best guess is that it's [beta cloth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_cloth), used for fireproofing spacesuits, although the Wikipedia article doesn't mention application in actual Spacecraft.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> THERMAL PROTECTION SYSTEM
>
> The SRMS is covered over its entire length with a multi-layer insulation thermal blanket system, which provides passive thermal control. This material consists of alternate layers of Kapton, Dacron scrim cloth and a Beta cloth outer covering. In extreme cold conditions, thermostatically controlled electric heaters (resistance elements) attached to critical mechanical and electronic hardware can be powered on to maintain a stable operating temperature.

https://ewh.ieee.org/reg/7/millennium/canadarm/canadarm_technical.html

Similarly the Soyuz material is also a TPS, referred to as an outer screen-vacuum thermal insulation (EVTI).

EVTI consists of multiple layers, just like MLI, with the outer layer made up of fiberglass, an inner facing layer of percale and screens located between them made of corrugated polyethylene terephthalate film with one-sided metallized surface, separated from each other by low-heat-conductive material such as glass veils.

Also of interest:

International Space Station (ISS) Soyuz Vehicle
Descent Module Evaluation of Thermal Protection
System (TPS) Penetration Characteristics

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20130013840/downloads/20130013840.pdf

Essentially wrt ISS, most MLI will be of similar composition, though there is some variance, depending on the module and age (Soviets/Russians), and also country of origin.

MMOD Protection and
Degradation Effects for
Thermal Control Systems

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42727502.pdf